# How do i get my keypair name, private keyfile and certificate file in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-instance-store

So following my last question about EBS and Instance store I found this on Amazon, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-snapshot-s3-linux.html. I'm up to "To upload your Amazon EC2 private key and X.509 certificate" and i cant work out where my    are. I think I have my keypair which is the .pem given to me when i make a new Key Pair in AWS Console. But at no point am i given private_keyfile or certificate_file.

I'm really stuck here and the AWS walk through talks about these 2 things like they should be starring in the face.

Any and all help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

In [my answer to your previous question](https://serverfault.com/a/528794/22362) I linked to how to create a private key and how to create and upload an X509 signing certificate:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_UploadCertificate.html

Specifically, you need to:

- Install OpenSSL
- Create a private key
- Create a signing certificate
- Upload the signing certificate to your IAM user

There's also the old method of using the [keys and certificates assigned to your AWS master account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#X509Credentials) but using the AWS master account is strongly discouraged by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the necessary files under "[Your Security Credentials](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential)"